# Decompress a .s file in c# windows form application

Tags: c#, compression

I am trying to decompress a .s file programmatically using c#. I have tried using all the possible methods I know but couldn't decompress it. My actual file would be a file.tar.gz, I have uncompressed .tar.gz using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar and ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip. In my uncompressed folder I would be having different files with "file_1.s" format. Can someone guide me plz?
Here is my function for decompressing:

```
   public void ExtractTGZ(String gzArchiveName, String destFolder)
   {
       Stream inStream = File.OpenRead(gzArchiveName);
       Stream gzipStream = new GZipInputStream(inStream);
       TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(gzipStream);
       tarArchive.ExtractContents(destFolder);
       tarArchive.Close();
       gzipStream.Close();
       inStream.Close();
   }
   public void ExtractTar(String tarFileName, String destFolder)
   {
       Stream inStream = File.OpenRead(tarFileName);
       TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(inStream);
       tarArchive.ExtractContents(destFolder);
       tarArchive.Close();
       inStream.Close();
   }
```

When a button event Occurs it will select the file.tar.gz from windows explorer and with next button it will start decompressing and its code is as shown below:

```
        private void OpenFileLocationEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (openLogs.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tbTargetFile.Text = openLogs.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void StartAnalysis(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (tbTargetFile.TextLength > 5)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Source File:" + tbTargetFile.Text + " ExtrctdDirectory:" + nextDirectory);
                _uc.ExtractTGZ(tbTargetFile.Text, nextDirectory);//Extract .tar.gz

                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(nextDirectory, "*.s");
                string filename = "";
                string targetFile = "";
                string newFile = "";
                int count = 0;
                foreach (string f in files)
                {//Changing File Type
                    filename = Path.GetFileName(f);
                    targetFile = nextDirectory + "//" + filename;
                    newFile = nextDirectory + "//File_" + count + ".tar";
                    File.Move(targetFile, newFile);
                    count += 1;
                    //FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(targetFile);
                    //finfo.MoveTo(Path.ChangeExtension(targetFile, ".txt"));
                }
                string[] tarfiles = Directory.GetFiles(nextDirectory, "*.tar");
                foreach (string f in tarfiles)
                {
                    filename = Path.GetFileName(f);
                    targetFile = nextDirectory + "\\" + filename;
                    MessageBox.Show("Traget File:" + targetFile + " ExtrctdDirectory:" + extrctdDirectory);
                    _uc.ExtractTar(targetFile, extrctdDirectory);
                    //_uc.ExtractTarByEntry(targetFile, extrctdDirectory, false);
                    //ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(targetFile, extrctdDirectory);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The real question is "what's the file format?" I think, rather than all of this speculative code trying to decompress it. `.s` files are normally assembly... What are the first few bytes? Have you tried running it past the `file` utility?

Comment: Yes .s is an assembly file format. I am able to decompress it using 7zip. I tried to change its format like .s to .zip or .tar but I am not able to do it. Whereas the programmatically converted file gets decompressed manually using 7 zip.

Comment: Have you tried to decompress file via code with console version of 7-zip?

Comment: Why do you think that an assembly file is actually a compressed tarball? They're completely different. What does 7-zip decompress it to?

Comment: @ Maciej Los I haven't tried console version of 7-zip

Comment: @ canton7: Actually this is a downloaded log from a device. 7-zip decompress it to a File(Type of file:File) which can be opened by Notepad++ and can be read as  a normal text file.

Comment: @ Maciej I Think my problem will be solved using 7-zip command line. I have tried manually and its working. Now I have to test programmatically. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a 7zip console application solved my problem. And this is my code.

```
private void StartAnalysis(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (tbTargetFile.TextLength > 5)
            {
                ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
                p.FileName = "7za.exe";
                p.Arguments = "x \"" + tbTargetFile.Text + "\" -o\"" + nextDirectory + "\"";
                p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                Process x = Process.Start(p);
                x.WaitForExit();
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(nextDirectory, "*.tar");
                string filename = "";
                string targetFile = "";
                foreach (string f in files)
                {
                    filename = Path.GetFileName(f);
                    targetFile = nextDirectory + "\\" + filename;
                }
                p.Arguments = "x \"" + targetFile + "\" -o\"" + nextDirectory + "\"";
                p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                x = Process.Start(p);
                x.WaitForExit();
                targetFile = nextDirectory + "\\*.s";
                p.Arguments = "x \"" + targetFile + "\" -o\"" + extrctdDirectory + "\"";
                p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                x = Process.Start(p);
                x.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
```